# Input redirection of child process in Java

Tags: java

I have a program that runs at the shell prompt as

```
% code arg1 arg2 < inputFile
```

i.e, gets its input redirected from a file. I need to have this in the form of Runtime().getRuntime().exec ("code arg1 arg2").

How do I get the input redirection? I have tried child.getOutputStream().write(bytes), after reading in the bytes from inputFile, does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `ProcessBuilder`, specifically the method [`redirectInput(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectInput%28java.io.File%29). It gives you what you need out of the box.